# change configmap mounted folder permissions in k8s

Tags: java, docker, kubernetes, jboss

I have folder that is mounted to my pod (from configmap) and i need to change the permissions from root:jboss to jboss:jboss

I have Dockerfile that im using its image for my pod , the user inside the image is jboss,and im copying some files from the localhost to the docker (those files are getting permission jboss:jboss

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM quay.io/wildfly/wildfly:26.1.0.Final
USER root
RUN yum install bind-utils -y
RUN yum -y install telnet
USER jboss
RUN mkdir -m 755 /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/data
COPY --chown=jboss:jboss ./localFolder/abc/*.war /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/
RUN chmod -R 755 /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/
```

then with helm im creating configmap from somefiles in my localhost and mount them to the pod to the `/opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/configuration` folder

and those files that are mounted are getting root:jboss permissions and not jboss:jboss

**configmap**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.labels.app }}-{{ .Values.labels.version | lower | replace "_" "-" | replace "." "-" }}-configs
data:
{{ tpl (.Files.Glob "config/*").AsConfig . | indent 2 }}
```

**deployment**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.labels.app }}-{{ .Values.labels.version | lower | replace "_" "-" | replace "." "-" }}
  namespace: {{ .Values.namespace }}
  labels:
    app: {{ .Values.labels.app }}
    version: {{ .Values.labels.version }}
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.spec.replicas }}
  strategy:
    type: {{ .Values.spec.strategy.type }}
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: {{ .Values.spec.strategy.rollingUpdate.maxSurge }}
      maxSurge: {{ .Values.spec.strategy.rollingUpdate.maxUnavailable }}
  minReadySeconds: {{ .Values.spec.minReadySeconds }}
  revisionHistoryLimit: {{ .Values.spec.revisionHistoryLimit }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ .Values.labels.app }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ .Values.labels.app }}
        version: {{ .Values.labels.version }}
      annotations:
        config.linkerd.io/proxy-cpu-limit: {{ .Values.linkerd_proxy_cpu_limit }}
        config.linkerd.io/proxy-cpu-request: {{ .Values.linkerd_proxy_cpu_request }}
        config.linkerd.io/proxy-memory-limit: {{ .Values.linkerd_proxy_memory_limit }}
        config.linkerd.io/proxy-memory-request: {{ .Values.linkerd_proxy_memory_request }}
        kubectl.kubernetes.io/default-container: {{ .Values.labels.app }}
        linkerd.io/inject: enabled
    spec:
      securityContext:
          fsGroup: 1000
          runAsUser: 1000
          runAsGroup: 1000
      serviceAccount: {{ .Values.spec.template.spec.serviceAccount }}
      volumes:
        - name: {{ .Values.labels.app }}-volume-1
          configMap:
            name: {{ .Values.labels.app }}-{{ .Values.labels.version | lower | replace "_" "-" | replace "." "-" }}-configs
        - name: {{ .Values.labels.app }}-volume-2
          configMap:
            name: {{ .Values.labels.app }}-{{ .Values.labels.version | lower | replace "_" "-" | replace "." "-" }}-configs
            defaultMode: 0777
        - name: {{ .Values.labels.app }}-volume-3
          configMap:
            name: {{ .Values.labels.app }}-{{ .Values.labels.version | lower | replace "_" "-" | replace "." "-" }}-configs
        - name: {{ .Values.labels.app }}-volume-4
          configMap:
            name: {{ .Values.labels.app }}-{{ .Values.labels.version | lower | replace "_" "-" | replace "." "-" }}-configs
        - name: secrets-store
          csi:
            driver: secrets-store.csi.k8s.io
            readOnly: true
            volumeAttributes:
              secretProviderClass: {{ .Values.labels.app }}-{{ .Values.labels.version | lower | replace "_" "-" | replace "." "-" }}-spc
            nodePublishSecretRef:
              name: secrets-store-creds
        - name: certificates-store
          csi:
            driver: secrets-store.csi.k8s.io
            readOnly: true
            volumeAttributes:
              secretProviderClass: {{ .Values.labels.app }}-{{ .Values.labels.version | lower | replace "_" "-" | replace "." "-" }}-cpc
            nodePublishSecretRef:
              name: secrets-store-creds
      containers:
      - name: {{ .Values.labels.app }}
        image: {{ .Values.spec.template.spec.containers.imageName }}
        command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
        args: ["chown -R jboss:jboss /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/configuration/* ;ls -la /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/configuration ; /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh -c standalone.xml -b 0.0.0.0 -bmanagement 0.0.0.0"]
        imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.spec.template.spec.containers.imagePullPolicy }}
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: {{ .Values.spec.template.spec.containers.resources.limits.cpu }}
            memory: {{ .Values.spec.template.spec.containers.resources.limits.memory }}
          requests:
            cpu: {{ .Values.spec.template.spec.containers.resources.requests.cpu }}
            memory: {{ .Values.spec.template.spec.containers.resources.requests.memory }}
        ports: #changeit
        - name: http
          containerPort: 55204
          protocol: TCP
        - name: debug
          containerPort: 8787
          protocol: TCP
        volumeMounts: #changeit
        - name: {{ .Values.labels.app }}-volume-1
          mountPath: /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/configuration/ccgw.properties
          subPath: ccgw.properties
        - name: {{ .Values.labels.app }}-volume-2
          mountPath: /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/configuration/logging.properties
          subPath: logging.properties
        - name: {{ .Values.labels.app }}-volume-3
          mountPath: /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/configuration/monitor.properties
          subPath: monitor.properties
        - name: {{ .Values.labels.app }}-volume-4
          mountPath: /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml
          subPath: standalone.xml
        - name: secrets-store
          mountPath: "/mnt/secrets-store"
          readOnly: true
        - name: certificates-store
          mountPath: /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/configuration/certificates/
      restartPolicy: Always
      nodeSelector:
        agentpool: {{ .Values.poolName }}
```

as you can see i have volume from configmap

```
volumes:
- name: {{ .Values.labels.app }}-volume-1
  configMap:
   name: {{ .Values.labels.app }}-{{ .Values.labels.version | lower | replace "_" "-" | replace "." "-" }}-configs
```

and im mounting it to the location

```
volumeMounts: #changeit
- name: {{ .Values.labels.app }}-volume-1
  mountPath: /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/configuration/ccgw.properties
```

and this file "ccgw.properties" for example is getting root:jboss permissions and not jboss:jboss

I also tried to run

```
command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
args: ["chown -R jboss:jboss /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/configuration/*"]
```

but it did not help

the issue that i need that file "ccgw.properties" to be **writeable**

Comment: You can't ever write to a file that's mounted from a ConfigMap.  Do you need some other sort of storage to hold that content, maybe a PersistentVolumeClaim?

Answer (score 0):

Use an `emptyDir` folder as an intermediate, and an initContainer.

1. Create an `emptyDir` volume
2. Create an `initContainer` that mounts the ConfigMap and the `emptyDir`
3. Your `initContainer` should copy the files from the ConfigMap mount point to the `emptyDir`, and set their permissions
4. Either mount the emptyDir where you want it in your main container, or mount it someplace else and move the files where you want them.